# How do I install the Intel HD Graphics driver for a Pentium P6200 CPU?

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics

I have a Pentium P6200 CPU with integrated Intel HD Graphics on Ubuntu 11.10. How do I install a driver...3D games under Wine run really slow.

Comment: I don't think a driver is needed (it's already in kernel and xorg) , but intel hd graphics do have a low performance than e.g Nvidia / ATI , did you find your window bluffy during movement , if so , the driver might be incompatible.

Comment: during the game its come super slow (warcraft 3 o.O) but the OS runs well, maybe using virtual box can run well? or i hav to do a dual boot?

Comment: No virtualbox will not make Magic and run the Game better, it's going to make it worse. What you see is what you get, that's the performance you have with the driver that's all you're going to get

Comment: well, i think i have to do a dual boot unfortunately

Comment: You're trying to run Warcraft 3, presumably under wine?  One possibility is that you've installed a 64bit version of Ubuntu and have a problem with the 32bit 3D drivers - if I remember correctly, there have been some (easy to fix) problems there.

Comment: It's possible to rung Warcraft3 with CrossOver , it doesn't stuck at all , but I never tried other than a ATI card

Answer (score 1):

You already have the Intel graphics drivers; they're included and enabled by default.  Unlike nVidia and AMD, Intel does not provide a proprietary driver for their GPUs on Linux, so you get the possible performance in the default install.

As mentioned in the comments, Intel GPUs (particularly pre-Sandybridge) are not very powerful; your performance expectations may be higher than the hardware is able to deliver.

Answer (score 1):

Your Intel graphics driver is not the issue. Running programs in a Windows Emulator will cause your depreciation in quality and framerate. To confirm this, try running a native Linux game from the Ubuntu Software Center, or running `glxgears` to check FPS speed, and see if you get the same quality. There are a lot of games to choose from, so try choosing something with similar 3D graphics.